# Res documentclass horizontal alignment issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

I'm using the `res` document class to create a simple resume. I'm going for something that looks like this [Creating a Resume Using LaTeX](http://maxburstein.com/blog/creating-resume-using-latex/) however I have to have my name and contact information centered at the top of the document instead of at the right and left.

I used the `center` environment, however it is only centering over the main content and ignoring the section headings. I understand that it is some sort of margin issue, however I am unsure of how to get it to center over the entire document. My source code is almost exactly like that in the link.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the longest name of section, the following (not elegant) solution centers name over text of sections:

```
 %   \documentclass[line, margin]{res}
\documentclass[margin, centered]{res}

    \begin{document}
\newlength{\maxmarg}
\settowidth{\maxmarg}{\textbf{EXPERIENCE}}
    \name{\hspace{0.5\maxmarg} Max Burstein}
    \address{\hspace{0.5\maxmarg}1234 Herp Derp Lane \\ 
\hspace{0.5\maxmarg}Rabble, FL 34343 \\
\hspace{0.5\maxmarg} (516) 516-5165}

    \begin{resume}
    \section{EDUCATION}
    Bachelor of Science in Blog Writing \\
    University of Y Combinator, Palo Alto, CA \\
    Minor: Fantasy Football \\
    Expected to graduate May 2013 \\
    GPA: 4.0

    \section{SKILLS}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Ruby
    \item C++
    \item Python
    \item System Administration
    \end{itemize}

    \section{EXPERIENCE}
    \textit{Detroit Red Wings Starting Center} \hfill 2011-2012 \\
    Was the starting center for the Detroit Red Wings until the strike :( Looking to play across the pond for a little bit. \\ [10pt]
    \textit{Green Bay Packers Starting Wide Receiver} \hfill 2010-2011 \\
    Was the starting WR for the Green Bay Packers during our super bowl run. I caught the game winning touchdown and decided to retire on top.

    \section{HONORS}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    May 2012 & \textbf{\textit{World's best double clicker}} \\ [5pt]
    July 2012 & \textbf{\textit{USA Candy Eating Champion}} \\ [5pt]
    December 2012 & \textbf{\textit{Inducted into the NFL Hall Of Fame}} \\
    \end{tabular}

    \end{resume}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more precise alingment, the initial value of `\maxmarg` should be enlarged by `\sectionskip`, which in `res` has the value 3.5ex plus 1ex minus -.2ex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any specifications about how the output should look, the following provides a simple solution to the centering while keeping the settings in the `res` class:

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[line, margin]{res}

\begin{document}
\name{\makebox[\textwidth]{Max Burstein}}
\address{\makebox[\textwidth]{1234 Herp Derp Lane \\ Rabble, FL 34343 \\ (516) 516-5165}}
% Uncomment below to see second output
%--------------------------------------------------------------
%\address{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
%   \parbox{0.2\textwidth}{%
%   \setlength\topsep{0pt} % removes the extra spaces created by the center environment
%  \setlength\parskip{0pt}
%   \begin{center}
%   1234 Herp Derp Lane \\ Rabble, FL 34343 \\ (516) 516-5165
%   \end{center}
%   }}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------- 
\begin{resume}
\section{EDUCATION} 
 Bachelor of Science in Blog Writing \\
 University of Y Combinator, Palo Alto, CA \\
 Minor: Fantasy Football \\
 Expected to graduate May 2013 \\
 GPA: 4.0

\section{SKILLS}
\begin{itemize}
\item Ruby
\item C++
\item Python
\item System Administration
\end{itemize}

\section{EXPERIENCE} 
\textit{Detroit Red Wings Starting Center} \hfill 2011-2012 \\
Was the starting center for the Detroit Red Wings until the strike :( Looking to play across the pond for a little bit. \\ [10pt]
\textit{Green Bay Packers Starting Wide Receiver} \hfill 2010-2011 \\
Was the starting WR for the Green Bay Packers during our super bowl run. I caught the game winning touchdown and decided to retire on top.

\section{HONORS}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
May 2012 & \textbf{\textit{World's best double clicker}} \\ [5pt]
July 2012 & \textbf{\textit{USA Candy Eating Champion}} \\ [5pt]
December 2012 & \textbf{\textit{Inducted into the NFL Hall Of Fame}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```